# Filtering does not work automatically when changing the sorting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting, react-hooks, filtering

I am building an application that has a database of videos that can be filtered by category and sorted by rating.

[image]

Filtering works after changing the options. However, when I change the categories of the video the filtering does not start automatically. I added useEffect but I don't know what else I can change and why it happens. Please help how to make the sorting not disappear when changing the cateogry.

UPDATE:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { getAllPrograms } from "../../helpers/getData";
import { TVProgram } from "../../models/models";
import Filters from "../Filters/Filters";
import ProgramsList from "../ProgramsList/ProgramsList";
import Sorting from "../Sorting/Sorting";
import "./HomePage.scss";

const HomePage = () => {
  const [programs, setPrograms] = useState<Array<TVProgram>>([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState<string>("movie,series");
  const [sortedPrograms, setSortedPrograms] = useState<TVProgram[]>(programs);

  const getPrograms = async (category: string) => {
    const programs = await getAllPrograms(category);
    setPrograms(programs);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPrograms(category);
  }, [category]);

  const updateCategory = (categoryName: string): void => {
    setCategory(categoryName);
    console.log("catName", categoryName);
  };

  const updatePrograms = (sortedPrograms: TVProgram[]): void => {
    setSortedPrograms(sortedPrograms);
    console.log("sortedPrograms", sortedPrograms);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <Filters
          updateCategory={updateCategory}
          currentCategory={category}
        ></Filters>
        <Sorting programs={programs} setPrograms={updatePrograms}></Sorting>
      </div>
      <ProgramsList programs={sortedPrograms}></ProgramsList>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { sortProgramsByOrder } from "../../helpers/helpers";
import { TVProgram } from "../../models/models";
import "./Sorting.scss";

interface SortingListProps {
  programs: TVProgram[];
  setPrograms: (programs: TVProgram[]) => void;
}

const Sorting = ({ programs, setPrograms }: SortingListProps) => {
  const OPTIONS = ["imdb rating descending", "imdb rating ascending"];
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>("");
  const [sortedPrograms, setSortedPrograms] = useState<TVProgram[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[0]) {
      setSortedPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "desc"));
    } else if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[1]) {
      setSortedPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "asc"));
    }
  }, [selectedOption, programs]);

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    console.log();
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
    setPrograms(sortedPrograms);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option selected>Sortuj</option>
        {OPTIONS.map((option) => (
          <option
            key={option}
            value={option}
            selected={option === selectedOption}
          >
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sorting;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect()` is a hook that prevents updates to a variable except in specific cases. Any variable passed into the array at the end of the `useEffect()` hook will cause the code inside to be run again when its value changes. The problem looks, at first glance, to be in the following part of your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[0]) {
      sortPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "desc"));
    } else if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[1]) {
      sortPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "asc"));
    }
  }, [selectedOption]);
```

The `[selectedOption]` is telling the hook to only do the sorting if the sorting order has changed. However, you want to call this hook if the order *or the contents* changes. As such, you want to replace this array with `[selectedOption, programs]` so that changes to the contents of the programs variable will also lead to the sorting being re-run.

If `programs` is updated in the hook and also set by the hook, this leads to a recursive call which is not good. Instead, let's change the displayed value to be a new variable (defined with useState) called `sortedPrograms`. Then your hook should look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[0]) {
      setSortedPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "desc"));
    } else if (selectedOption === OPTIONS[1]) {
      setSortedPrograms(sortProgramsByOrder(programs, "asc"));
    }
  }, [selectedOption, programs]);
```

Comment: I passed the category to Sorting and changed the arrays in useEffect but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: @guziczek300 my mistake - you want to pass in the `programs` variable, not the `category` variable.

Comment: hmm when I add [selectedOption, programs] and change the sorting, the programs don't change and in the console goes their unfinished fetch

Comment: "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render"

Comment: @guziczek300 That means it is successfully updating the programs variable but that then itself triggers another round of updates, quickly hitting the limit on number of nested updates. I will update the answer with how to get to working code from there.

Comment: ok, thanks! one more question if I can. But what about sortPrograms function which update programs in HomePage? Create another useEffect?

  useEffect(() => {
    sortPrograms(sortedPrograms);
  }, [sortedPrograms]);

Comment: You shouldn't need that, no.

Comment: If I remove it I do not see any change in the programs, they do not sort at all. if I add as I wrote it is again the problem of the unfinished loop

Comment: Properly your `sortPrograms()` method should be called `setPrograms()` as that is what it is doing. You would need a `sortedPrograms` variable from `useState()` and then update the value of the variable via `setSortedPrograms()` from inside the last `useEffect()` in my answer. The `setSortedPrograms` method will need to be passed to the Sorting element.

Comment: sorry could you still look at my update code because I think I am giving something wrong though :(

Comment: Looks like the big change left to make is to move the `sortedPrograms` variable into the HomePage file. You should define it in the same place as `programs` and then make your `<ProgramsList>` element take the `sortedPrograms` instead of `programs` as a variable.

Comment: could you still take a look? The sortedPrograms array from HomePage in the console is empty all the time, I add default value as `programs` but it doesn't work

Comment: Looking again, you need to remove the `sortedPrograms` and `setSortedPrograms()` definitions from the Sorting component, and where you are using `setSortedPrograms()` now you want to use the `setPrograms()` function that is passed through from the HomePage. This will let the Sorting component communicate the sorted list back up to the HomePage.